# Doctrine2 - @OneToOne unidirectional entity returns cascade persistence error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the following class:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository")
* @ORM\Table(name="my_data")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Data extends ModelEntity
{

/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Customer $userId
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $userId;

//in the class are more methods + getters and setters @not important
}
```

The Customer Entity is not a class of mine, therefore I want this relationship to be unidirectional and don't care how the Customer looks like (minus the `id` field).

Now from [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) I got that I don't need any other `cascade={"persist"}` thingy like in the error I get:

```
exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 
'A new entity was found through the relationship 
'Data#userId' that was not configured to cascade persist operations 
 for entity: 
 Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer@0000000035d66eab000000001b1ed901. 
 To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() 
 on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  
 this association in the mapping for example 
 @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). 
 If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
'Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer#__toString()' to get a clue.'
```

what am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this error?

PS: I don't want to modify or save any information in this Customer, just to have a reference to the entity.

LE: Due this info [Doctrine documentation: cascade-persist](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#persistence-by-reachability-cascade-persist) I will output also some code from where the error is triggered. As it says in the documentation:

`New entities in a collection not marked as cascade: persist will produce an Exception and rollback the flush() operation.`

the error is trown by the following **flush()**

```
$this->entityModel->persist($this->getDataInstance());
$this->entityModel->flush();
```

and the `getDataInstance` method is *Data* entity that has a *Customer*, the *Customer* Object is found from its repository through method *findBy('Customer', id)*. The *Customer* entity it is never new instatiated or modified, therefore no need to persist it.

The `getDataInstance`:

```
protected function getDataInstance()
{
    if (is_null($this->data)) {
        $this->initData();
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

and the `initData`:

```
private function initData()
{
    if (is_null($this->data)) {
        $this->data = new Data();
        /**
         * @var \Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer $customer
         */
        $customer = $this->entityModel->getRepository('Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer')->findOneBy(['id' => $this->session->sUserId]);
        $this->data->setUserId($customer);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Still didn't find an answer, but I found some leads after speaking with someone on the doctrine #IRC channel.

Here is the conversation:

> p1: did your Customer entity maybe get detached? for instance de/serialization, using more than one entity manager or calling $em->clear() can lead to detaching
>
> p1: do you expect to create new customer? if no then either you did, or it "found" an already existing entity which would suggest one of the above
>
> me: $em->clear() is not called by me for sure
>
> me: the de/serialization I'm not sure ... the shop has a HTTP-cache that can do that
>
> p1: where do you get the entity from? yes, cache might do it if it caches customers without knowing about orm
>
> me: and I don't expect to create a new customer, I just called from the repository one
>
> me: $customer = $this->swagModelManager->getRepository('Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer')->findOneBy(['id' => $this->session->sUserId]);
>
> me: which retruns either null or the object
>
> p1: is $this, respectively $this->data cached between requests possibly?
>
> me: the method findOneBy can be find in the EntityRepository.php (line 192)
>
> me: hmm I don't know, the thing is on my local host and other installation that never happens, but on 1 client server it does :D and I assumed that has to do with the caches and his settings on the server
>
> me: so if that's the problem how can I fix it ?
>
> me: to don't call the cascade persist
>
> p1: the detached entity can be reattached by doing "$entity = $em->refresh($entity)" or "$entity = $em->merge($entity)" (they differ in handling of possible changes between the entity state and the db - refresh reloads the data from db - "resets", merge updates the db) - but that is not a fix if you do not know why it happens - you probably can't tell when it is safe to do it
>
> me: I know, it is bad that I cannot reproduce that - thanks for the tips!
>
> p1: the main thing - if EM says it found "new" entity and it already exists in the DB, it is not "managed" by that EM - either it has been detached somehow or it is still attached but to a different EM instance
>
> me: then an $em->refresh($entity) before the persist should sufice, right? because I don't want to change anything related to this Entity
>
> p1: you would have to do that to the referenced customer, so "$entity->customer = $em->refresh($entity->customer)" - but beware of possible side effects of reassigning that (any events, side effects in getter or similar stuff if you have it)

Due to the fact that I cannot reporduce the error right now, I cannot say if the end of the conversation is the right answer or not. When I will know for sure I will revise the question/answer.

Comment: im a little confused. your `getDataInstance` method returns an already persisted database object? *which is found by a repository through findBy('Customer', id)*. From that it looks like youre not dealing with a new entity, but one that already exists.  can we see `getDataInstance()`?